# Python 3.3.0. I get this error import error : no module named request. what to do ? i use windows 7

Tags: python

import urllib.request 
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/prices.html") 
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")

print ("Buy!")

Answer (score 0):

Use just import urllib then put the statement below that.